# How can I remove users from my contacts in Gmail based on a request?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I wish to update my contacts list as I occasionally send emails to clients. I wish to provide them the option to be removed from my contacts. How can I achieve this using Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [CRM like Zoho](http://crm.zoho.com) instead of Gmail, which is not made for that kind of client management

Comment: Could you please go into detail? The current answer as it stands is not sufficient.

Comment: A CRM is a Contact Relations Manager. It will store contacts for you and more specifically has the ability to record whether or not that contact wishes to be emailed. They even provide you a small HTML form that you can place on a website so that the person may unsubscribe. Again the name of this internet application is called Zoho CRM, and its a package that comes along with many different features.

Comment: That's not really what I am asking. Can you provide details on how Zoho can remove users from contacts in Gmail.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that Gmail isn't made for managing contacts in the way that you'd like. Zoho is made for that kind of client management. I'm suggesting that instead of using Gmail you use Zoho

Comment: You will need to update your original answer to state as such.